# How to find the topological dimension of finite set of points in projective space?

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $X \subset \mathbb{P}^n$ be a quasi-projective algebraic set. Show that $\operatorname{dim} X=0$ if and only if $X$ is a finite union of points.

So I know some theorems such as Krull's PID theorem and the fact that if we have an affine variety $X$ (in affine space) the topological dimension of $X$ is the same as the Krull dimension of the coordinate ring $K[X]$. But the problem I am having right now is I'm not sure how to apply these results in the case where we are working on projective space.

Comment: Hint: do you know some copies of affine space inside projective space? Can you connect what you know about the affine situation to the projective situation?

Comment: How does the dimension of $X $ compare to the dimension of $\overline{X}$? Now, what is the irreducible decomposition of $\overline{X}$?